# Swing: Problems with getting my simple GUI functional

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to build a counter that simply increments or decrements an integer using a GUI. Please can someone help me where I have gone wrong. My buttons just do not increment or decrement the starting integer value of 0.

```
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
     import javax.swing.JTextArea;
     import javax.swing.JTextField;

     import java.awt.BorderLayout;
     import java.awt.Container;
     import java.awt.GridLayout;
     import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
     import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

     import javax.swing.*;

     import org.omg.CORBA.TCKind;

     public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    // Field Variables
    private int counter;
    private int currentNumber = 0;


    // Methods
    public void setCounter(int counter){
        currentNumber = counter;
    }

    public int getCounter(){
        return currentNumber;
    }

    public void IncrementCounter() {
        currentNumber++;

    }

    public void DecrementCounter() {
        currentNumber = 222;
    }

    public MainFrame(String title) {
        super(title);

        // SetLayout
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));

        // Add Swing components
        final JTextField tCounter = new JTextField();
        tCounter.setEditable(false);
        tCounter.setText(currentNumber + "");

        JTextField label = new JTextField();
        label.setText("The Count: ");
        label.setEditable(false);

        JButton btn1 = new JButton("up");
        JButton btn2 = new JButton("down");

        // Add components to content pane

        getContentPane().add(btn1);
        getContentPane().add(btn2);
        getContentPane().add(label);
        getContentPane().add(tCounter);

        // Add btn1 ad btn2 behaviour.
        btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                IncrementCounter();
            }
        });

        // Add btn2 Behaviour
        btn2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                DecrementCounter();

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you change the count, you have to update your label **tCounter**. For that purpose, convert the tCounter variable to a field, add the **updateLabel()** method, call it from **IncrementCount** and **DecrementCount**. Call it from the constructor as well to initialize the text.

```
JTextField tCounter=new JTextField();

void updateLabel(){
  tCounter.setText(currentNumber+"");
}


public void IncrementCounter() {
  currentNumber++;
  updateLabel()
}

...
```

Updated Code:

```
package foo;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
// Field Variables
private int counter;
private int currentNumber = 0;

// Methods
public void setCounter(int counter) {
    currentNumber = counter;
}

public int getCounter() {
    return currentNumber;
}

public void IncrementCounter() {
    currentNumber++;
    updateLabel();
}

void updateLabel() {
    tCounter.setText(currentNumber + "");
}

public void DecrementCounter() {
    currentNumber = 222;
    updateLabel();
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    MainFrame frame = new MainFrame("Foo");
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

final JTextField tCounter = new JTextField();

public MainFrame(String title) {
    super(title);

    // SetLayout
    setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));

    // Add Swing components
    tCounter.setEditable(false);
    updateLabel();

    JTextField label = new JTextField();
    label.setText("The Count: ");
    label.setEditable(false);

    JButton btn1 = new JButton("up");
    JButton btn2 = new JButton("down");

    // Add components to content pane

    getContentPane().add(btn1);
    getContentPane().add(btn2);
    getContentPane().add(label);
    getContentPane().add(tCounter);

    // Add btn1 ad btn2 behaviour.
    btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            IncrementCounter();
        }
    });

    // Add btn2 Behaviour
    btn2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            DecrementCounter();

        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: @user3274549: by calling `setText(...)` on the JLabel with the new text that you want displayed.

Comment: @user3274549: however this advice may be a little off as you appear to be trying to display your count in a JTextField. If so, then you'll want to update the JTextField, and again you'd call `setText(...)`.

Comment: Thanks Ruediste.  I've done exactly what you have suggested, which made a lot of sense to me. but now when I click on either of my buttons, I am getting exceptions...not sure what is happening.

Comment: I just tried it out myself. I do not get any exceptions. Did you do some fancy stuff to your code in the mean time? Added my code to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems in your code. First, you never actually update the label. This is not done on its own and must be done in the `actionPerformed()` methods. Two, you must use the method `repaint()` on any component you wish to update. Here is a version of your `actionPerformed()` methods that works in your program.

```
// Add btn1 ad btn2 behaviour.
    btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            IncrementCounter();
            tCounter.setText(currentNumber + "");
            tCounter.repaint();
        }
    });

    // Add btn2 Behaviour
    btn2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            DecrementCounter();
            tCounter.setText(currentNumber + "");
            tCounter.repaint();
        }
    });
```

I would suggest you do a little research into updating swing in Java.